# How to save the system(cmd) result in a variable?

Tags: c

I've the function `system(cmd)` that executes a command which returns two numbers to the terminal:

```
977190
977190
```

How can I assign one of these numbers to a variable to use in the program? It doesn't matter if it is a char or an int variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `posix` is an option, you can switch from `system` to `popen`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *, const char *);
int pclose(FILE *);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd;

    cmd = popen("echo 123", "r");
    if (cmd == NULL)
    {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char result[1024];    
    long number = 0;

    if (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd))
    {
        number = strtol(result, NULL, 10);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    printf("%ld\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123
```