# How do I retrieve the contents of POPEN in C?

Tags: c, popen, fgets

I have code that looks like this:

```c
        char* buff = malloc(strlen(argv[1])+200);

        if (!buff)
        {
            printf("%s\n", "Error allocating memory!");
            return -1;
        }

        sprintf(buff, "%s%s%s%s", "gcc ", argv[1], " -o ", findChars(argv[1], '.'));

        FILE* command = popen(buff, "r");

        // NEED TO RETRIEVE OUTPUT OF POPEN

        pclose(command);
```

And this works, but I need to save the output of the POPEN to a char* so I can read it.
(This is in C)

Comment: With `fgets` or any function able to read the opened file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032512/1606345

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An open pipe is just a `FILE*`, so any function that can read from a `FILE*` can do this. For example:

```
fgets(some_buffer, sizeof(some_buffer), command);
```

Error handling, repeated reads in case the buffer is too small, all the usual stuff about reading files in C also applies here.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works like a charm. The only question is, how would I allocate enough memory (how ever much memory my command's output is) to my buffer where it's being saved to prevent a buffer overflow? Apart from that tysm :)

Comment: Again, [any question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747086/reading-the-whole-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-c) about reading files also applies here.